# Can I exclude blanks / 0 from an ArrayFormula countif?

Tags: google-sheets, countif, array-formulas

I have a simpe ArrayFormula:

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(I2:I,J2:J))
```

How do I filter out the null counts?

The results I expect are rows that actually have results.  I don't want a sheet full of 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try either this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I2:I), COUNTIF(I2:I, J2:J), ))
```

or this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(J2:J), COUNTIF(I2:I, J2:J), ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that second one worked.  I need to dig into that LEN function. I've seen it thrown around, but I really don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid displaying all `0`s in the relevant column (whether because 'I' *or* 'J' cell empty/blank) you might format it as:

```
#;
```